# Out of bounds string array java

Tags: java

I am facing a problem that I can't take elements from ArrayList and push them to my new String array. Actually right now I`m feeling lost. Receiving an exception out of bounds, but after a check with printing elements by their id everything works? By the way my darbuotojuArray looks like this:

> Programuotojas: X X 1 X

Here's my code:

```
public String[] renkantDarbuotojus() {
    String[] darbuotojaiIKomanda = new String[2];
    if (darbuotojuArray.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Nera darbuotoju kuriuos butu galima prideti i komanda.");
        System.out.println("Pridekite nauju darbuotoju");
        meniu.valdiklis();
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < darbuotojuArray.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + i + " " + darbuotojuArray.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Pasirinkite pirmaji darbuotoja pagal ID");
        Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userSelects = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
        darbuotojaiIKomanda[0] = String.valueOf(darbuotojuArray.get(userSelects));
        darbuotojuArray.remove(userSelects);
        System.out.println("Pasirinkite antraji darbuotoja pagal ID");
        int userSelects2 = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
        darbuotojaiIKomanda[1] = String.valueOf(darbuotojuArray.get(userSelects2));
        darbuotojuArray.remove(userSelects2);
    }
    return darbuotojaiIKomanda;
}
```

Comment: What are `userSelects` and `userSelects2` going to look like? What is `X X 1 X` as well?

Comment: depending on your input for `userSelects` and `userSelects2`, your array might go out of bounds

Comment: a user selects by id other users whose are in arraylist and first X is user name, second surname, third age and fourth language

Comment: @AbhishekPatel ++. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

So, you are removing an item from the list`darbuotojuArray.remove(userSelects);`, which will change all the IDs.  You either need to print your list again so the user can select the correct ID, or you can do this:

```
 int userSelects2 = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
 if(userSelects2 == userSelects)
      System.out.println("Error, ID has been removed");  
 else if(userSelects2 > userSelects)
      userSelects2 = userSelects2 -1;
```